# How to move right and left with touch?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to move character to left and right from whole screen and if i move from anywhere to left or to right it need to move only how much i have now = 1.5f

I have this code and works perfect but it works only with mouse not with touch screen:

```
if (!isMoving && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    desiredPos = transform.position + Vector3.right * 1.52f;
    isMoving = true;
}

if (!isMoving && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
{
    desiredPos = transform.position - Vector3.right * 1.52f;
    isMoving = true;
}

if (isMoving)
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, desiredPos, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    // this == is true if the difference between both
    // vectors is smaller than 0.00001
    if (transform.position == desiredPos)
    {
        isMoving = false;

        // So in order to eliminate any remaining difference
        // make sure to set it to the correct target position
        transform.position = desiredPos;
    }
}
```

I tried to implement this code and this is not working

```
private void Update()
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    int i = 0;
    //loop over every touch found
    while (i < Input.touchCount)
    {
        if (!isMoving && Input.GetTouch(i).position.x > ScreenWidth / 2)
        {
            //move right
            desiredPos = transform.position + Vector3.right * 1.52f;
            isMoving = true;
        }
        if (!isMoving && Input.GetTouch(i).position.x < ScreenWidth / 2)
        {
            //move left
            desiredPos = transform.position - Vector3.right * 1.52f;
            isMoving = true;
        }
        ++i;
    }


    if (isMoving)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, desiredPos, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        // this == is true if the difference between both
        // vectors is smaller than 0.00001
        if (transform.position == desiredPos)
        {
            isMoving = false;

            // So in order to eliminate any remaining difference
            // make sure to set it to the correct target position
            transform.position = desiredPos;
        }
    }
}
```

This second code moves character too much to left or to right and i need to move exact like in first code but with touch swipe to left or to right.

I want something like this to move exact 1.5f

[image: e]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To behave same as `GetMouseButtonDown`, you need also check the phrase of the touch:

```
Input.GetTouch(i).phrase == TouchPhase.Began
```

Comment: how i can implement this to my first code please help me on my example

Comment: Due to the OP being new to `Touch` inputs it would probably be helpfull to add a note about checking for a Touches before checking for the state of any given Touch.